# Change xml element value dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="api_response")]
public class ApiResponse 
{
        [XmlElement( ElementName = "api_name")]
        public string api_name { get; set; }
}
```

Above is a class with specified class

I want to change **ElementName="api_response"**

api_response value to dynamic values like

some time it should be

```
ElementName="first response"
```

or

```
ElementName="second response"
```

I have to change this dynamically

I have tried some thing like this but dint get worked out

```
 XmlAttributeOverrides config1 = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
 config1.Add(typeof(ORM.ApiResponse), "ElementName",new XmlAttributes {XmlDefaultValue = "myvalue" };
```

but its not working

please help

Thanks

Comment: are you doing this for serialization? what is the purpose?

Comment: i have to show root element as "first response" or second response"  but it always showing api_response

Comment: You could use DOM on the final XML and change the root element's name

Comment: can i have any example please

Comment: Note that xml element names can not contain spaces. Also check the design, if using different xml-elements for the first and second response is suitable, i.e. do they have actually different layout? If so, consider declaring two different xml-structures - if not, try to put the first/second distinction in e.g. an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for serialization, this will do:

```
            var apiResponse = new ApiResponse() { api_name = "test api" };

            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"apiData.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(
                    typeof(ApiResponse), new XmlRootAttribute("newRoot"));
                ser.Serialize(writer,apiResponse);
            }
```

Edit:

To return a string, you can use a `stringwriter`.

```
var apiResponse = new ApiResponse() { api_name = "test api" };                
using (stringwriter = new StringWriter())
{
    var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(
    typeof(ApiResponse));
    ser.Serialize(stringwriter,apiResponse);
    var xmlString= stringwriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    return xmlString;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to return?

Comment: i have to return this generated xml

Comment: The xml will be saved in file "apiData.xml". You can load this file from that location.